# Get the top 2 teams from array following this rules in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [
    {id: 1, p: 7, gs: 11, ga: 7, gd: 4},
    {id: 2, p: 4, gs: 10, ga: 8, gd: 2},
    {id: 3, p: 3, gs: 7, ga: 9, gd: -2},
    {id: 4, p: 3, gs: 5, ga: 9, gd: -4}
];
```

The values being:

`p` --> Points

`gs` --> Goals Scored

`ga` --> Goals Against

`gd` --> Goal Difference

---

Here's the thing:

I need to eliminate 2 of them based on this rules:

1. Points
2. Goal Difference
3. Goals Scored

So in this case, `id[1]` and `id[2]` pass before they have more points than the other two.

However, if the `id[2]` and `id[3]` were to have the same points, you'd have to look at goal difference. The team with the greatest goal differnce advances.

However, the may also have the same goal Difference, but one of them scored more goals, then, the team who scored more goals advances.

Finally, if they have the same amount of goals scored and goal difference and points, a Math.random() settles the tiebreaker.

I don't know how to go with this because there can be a lot of cases. Is there a way to do this without checking each case separately?

Comment: That `Math.random()` is a bit "strange", in so far that it could be dependent on a refresh to see which of the 2 is "better", or will you store this data? For the other questions, no, you will have to compare all cases when necessary (but early exits are ofcourse the way to go)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sort them after the criterias:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => 
  b.p  - a.p  ||
  b.gd - a.gd ||
  b.gs - a.gs ||
  Math.random() - 0.5
);
```

And to then "eliminate" the last two, just splice them away:

```
arr.splice(-2, 2);
```

And thats it :)

Comment: `And to then "eliminate" the last two, just splice them away:` or just get the first two `arr.slice(0, 2)`. Probably more of a philosophical way of looking at it but I'm adding it here for information only.

Comment: Such a simple and sexy solution, and I was already sketching down a bunch of ifs, that's the beauty of programming!